# Modern books on native C++ development

Tags: c++, windows

I was going through the Hilo tutorial series [*Developing C++ Applications for Windows 7*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708696.aspx); seemed pretty interesting.

What modern books that go into details of developing C++ based applications for Windows 7? It should show how to take advantage of Windows 7 features and based on "modern" C++ (templates, Unicode, etc.). Not looking for old school Petzold or MFC type books (sorry). Also should feature native code development (i.e. no Qt-/wx-type 3rd party libraries). The 3rd party libraries seems to be at least a generation behind and don't seem to leverage the latests features (ex. Ribbon, Animation etc.).

Comment: Ok, but Petzold's book is still extremely relevant. I recommend it at least for some background and reference on Win32 specific bits. But I think this tutorial series will be a good resources for many people!

Comment: BobbyShaftoe, I understand where you are coming from, but the Petzold book is seriously old. I remember reading it way back. The latest edition is from 1999!. I agree the message pump stuff is fundamental but GDI, Font, old school windows controls, multithreading etc etc. are just outdated. I would read probably the first 200 pages or find a tutorial on message pump. The book is huge! Absolutely not worth going through all the 1500 pages today.

Comment: You say native code development, but your only stated complaint against 3rd party libraries are that they lag behind. So would you at all consider .Net (particularly C# + WPF) since those not as "3rd party" and are generally more up to date with modern features?

Comment: UndeadFish, Are you sure it is C# and WPF or is it C# and Silverlight or something else in 5 years. Are all the Win 7 features implemented and optimized in .NET 4.0 or do we need to wait until .NET 6.0 catches up on performance/functionality. See the recent Evernote debacle. I don't even think they were implementing any Windows 7 functionality. Anyway that is a WHOLE another thread, don't want to hijack this one. Just consider that I'm not looking at .NET right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a book for just Win32 C++ for beginners](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575127/54262)

Comment: List of X questions ["aren't really what we want,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason) but you should get better results on a blog or other [discussion site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions).

Comment: Roger, I looked at the possible duplicate thread and it contains exactly the suggestions that I don't want (Petzold, MFC). As I mentioned in the Original post, if you look at the Hilo tutorial here are some of the topics covered - Ribbon UI, Touch, Animation, HTTP services. All relevant to programming in 2010, none of the - GDI, win16 to win32 thunking type information. In any case, the question was very specific (looking for certain type of books/information), the .NET discussion was a segue in response to a comment.

Comment: Fair enough if you feel you have reasons to rule out .Net (though I have no idea what the Evernote thing is about), but I asked the question because for any modern Windows (GUI) programming many people would first recommend .Net/C#/WPF especially when you've ruled out all the C++ frameworks out there. I can't help with good resources for writing modern programs entirely at the raw Windows API level. But I would suggest you re-consider a framework that can do much of the dirty work for you and then you only drop down to the WinAPI for the features it lacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend that you ensure you're familiar with the theory in winprog.org/tutorial, then Ivor Horton's book (below), and then finally check out the WTL library.

The examples on the ribbon code in the Hilo articles use the windows API, which relies on COM objects to create the ribbon.  ATL constructs like the CComPtr manage the lifetime of the ribbon objects and interfaces.

Because of this, I'd recommend that you ensure that you understand the basics of writing COM client code - e.g. You should understand CoCreateInstance, QueryInterface and smart pointers.  ATL Internals (search on Amazon) is the essential reference on COM, but it is heavy going.

WTL wraps the detail of creating the ribbon and accessing it, but WTL was made for COM programmers looking for a windowing API, so it's not an easy API to begin with if you don't have experience of COM programming with ATL.

WTL supports the latest windows features, like ribbons etc.  Don't expect any books on the subject though, there aren't any.  M$ open sourced WTL some years ago, so the code is available to read, so you can figure out how everything works by reading the code.  It's quite advanced though, you may want to look at it after you've had a look at the alternatives first.

Google uses WTL for the UI for Chrome.

I suspect you should Start with [Ivor Horton's beginning Visual C++ 2010](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ivor-Hortons-Beginning-Visual-Programmer/dp/0470500883/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1289603117&sr=8-1), it'll be a good all round introduction.

If you're looking for a great programming book for windows though, you can't do better than [windows via c/c++ by Jeff richter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-via-PRO-Developer-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735624240/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1289603186&sr=1-1) - by far the best windows coding book I've ever bought.

If you are interested in WTL, then look at [Michael dunn's series wtl for mfc programmers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc1.aspx) on code project.

Finally, there is no one book that hand hold the would be c++ GUI developer through all this, and that's a big gap in the market.  I've often wondered why no one has picked up on this, given the popularity of c++

Answer (score 1):

I still think that Stroustrup's The C++ programming language is a required read (cover to cover) for every C++ programmer. Then, add the Essential C++/STL series by Scott Meyers for some additional tips and advice.

Comment: I believe Nathan's question was more targeted at Windows 7 programming, not general C++ programming.  That's not to say that I'm not a fan of Stroustrup's book; in fact I'm a HUGE fan.  But Stroustrup's tome seems geared more for platform-neutral and -agnostic C++ programming, not specific to Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still 'modern', but [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) is a great resource on templates and generic algorithms.

Comment: I don't think that's the type of "modern" the OP is looking for. I think the OP is looking for a more practical book that discusses real-world application design and development. _Modern C++ Design_ isn't really about modern C++ application design; it's about the extraordinary capabilities of generic programming in C++ (it's subtitle, "Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied," is much more descriptive of what the book is about).

Comment: @James, I guess you're right, but it's a great book on generic algorithms!! :)

Comment: _Great_ does not do the book justice; it's an _epic_ -- nay, _legendary_ -- book. :-) If every C++ developer read and understood that book, the world would be a far better place and there would be much less poorly written C++ code.

Comment: @James McNellis  this book challenges every programmer's intelligence to their extreme, we should not anticipate that every C++ programmer is that smart and diligent. on the contrary, let's use C++ as simple as we can...